# How to compile Google Protobuf command line interface compile

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to raw decode a protobuf binary. I installed the google protobuf library from the source code https://github.com/google/protobuf
I am able to use the command line to decode raw a protobuf binary using the command `protoc --decode_raw <encodedfile>`. I want to be able to do this programmatically using the c++ library. Something similar to the following example in the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.command_line_interface

However trying to compile a simple piece of code does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h>
using namespace google::protobuf::compiler;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface cli_;
    cerr << "Compiled And Run" << endl;

}
```

Compile command

```
c++  my_program.cc  -o my_program -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -lpthread
```

I see the following error

```
my_program.cc:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::CommandLineInterface()'
my_program.cc:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::~CommandLineInterface()'
my_program.cc:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::~CommandLineInterface()'
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Have you built the protobuf libs? Using the steps [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/src).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf compiler is in a different library, `libprotoc`. You need to link against it

```
c++  my_program.cc  -o my_program -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotoc -lprotobuf -lpthread
```

Note that `-lprotoc` needs to appear before `-lprotobuf`, because libprotoc uses functions of libprotobuf.